# How do I create a bucket and multiple subfolders at once in AWS S3 using Boto3?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3, bucket

I'm able to create one directory at the top level using

```
s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
```

I want to create a new bucket and subfolders so I have a directory structure like:

```
-top_level_bucket
    -sub_folder
        -sub_sub_folder
```

I want to do something like this to create everything at once if not already existent:

```
path = 'top_level_bucket/sub_folder/sub_sub_folder'
s3.create_bucket(Bucket=path)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You are confusing buckets and object prefixes. Please read through the [Introduction to Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html). Looks like you want one bucket with a folder structure. You can easily create that prefix by just uploading a single object using that prefix.

Comment: In addition,  so call "directory tree rights" doesn't exists in S3.  If you want to control who can or cannot write to some "prefix", you need to insert policy to control it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no concept of a 'sub-bucket' in Amazon S3.

Amazon S3 is actually a flat object storage service. It **does not use directories**.

Instead, files are uploaded with a path, eg:

```
aws s3 cp file.txt s3://my-bucket/bob/files/file.txt
```

The full name of the object will be: `bob/files/file.txt`

It *looks* and *behaves* like there are directories, but they are not actually there. In fact, you can run the above command and it will automatically 'create' the `bob` and `files` directory, but they are not actually there! If you delete the object, those directories will disappear (because they were never actually there!).

**Bottom line:** Upload files to where ever you wish, even if the buckets do not exist. Don't worry about creating a folder structure in advance.